# Frequency in linked Lists

Tags: c++, list, frequency

I'm trying to make a fn called frequency that returns the frequency of a given integer in the linked list. 
so far:

```
    int IntSLList::frequency(int e)
    {

           int total = 0;
           IntSLLNode *temp;
           for (temp = head; temp!=0 && !(temp-> info ==e) ; temp = temp->next)
           {
                 total++;   
            }
          return total;
```

but the number that it returns (should return 1) but returns 8
my linked list has 10 elements (0-9

Comment: Try moving your condition to increase `total` *inside* the `for` loop (`while` might make more sense), and keep the `for` loop strictly checking for the end of the list.

Comment: For this amount of code and that size of list, you should be able to pretty easily step through the code line by line and watch what is happening, when the values change, and when the `for` loop exits.

Answer (score 1):

The check for equal to e should be done in the body of the for loop.

```
int IntSLList::frequency(int e)
{
    int total = 0;
    IntSLLNode *temp;
    for (temp = head; temp!=0 ; temp = temp->next)
    {
        if( temp->info == e )
            total++;   
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Use `nullptr` instead of 0 when checking for null.

Comment: Actually, just `... ; temp; ...` (no need to compare against anything, and also `temp` does not need to be outside the loop here), but `while (temp)` makes more sense than a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

This condition: `temp!=0 && !(temp-> info ==e)` causes you to count up to the first of 2 things:

1. The end of the list.
2. The first time you reach `e`.

This is not your desired behavior, so you need to adjust the condition. What do we want?

1. We go from the beginning of the list to the end, regardless of the number, so our for loop looks like: `for(IntSLLNode *temp = head; temp; temp = temp->next)`.
2. At each element we want to check if we have a number equal `e`:

---

```
 if (temp->info == e) {
     total++;
}
```

This gives us the final loop:

```
int IntSLList::frequency(int e) {
    int total = 0;
    for (IntSLLNode *temp = head; temp; temp = temp->next) {
        if( temp->info == e ) {
            total++;
        }   
    }
    return total;
}
```